# Geting list in python using map function

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
>>>a=int(input())
>>>b=list(map(int,input().strip().split()))[:a]
>>>print(b)
```

While I entered this code in different compiler may gave different answers i wish to learn the use of `[:a]`
What is the use of `[:a]`?

Comment: the [:a] is acting as a slice of the list, imagine a was set to 5. and b was a list of 10 items. [:a] would be evaluated as [:5], which says from the start of the list take all items until index 5, I,E all items from index 0 to index 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of [:a] is that it indicates the size of the list that how many elements can be entered in that given list.
b=list(map(int,input().strip().split())) ----> this indicates the append of elements enter values with spaces it will append all integers.
with use of the slice operator [:a] it limits the appending of integers with the list

```
enter code here
>>> a=4
>>> b=list(map(int,input('Enter values with space:').strip().split()))
>>> print(b)
Enter values with space:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> a=4
>>> b=list(map(int,input('Enter values with space).strip().split()))[:a]
>>> print(b)
Enter values with space:1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
[1,2,3,4]    #Though we enter many values it accepts only first four values that you entered
```

Answer (score 0):

[:] this is called slicing. Slicing in Python is a feature that enables accessing parts of sequences like strings, tuples, and lists. You can also use them to modify or delete the items of mutable sequences such as lists. Slices can also be applied on third-party objects like NumPy arrays, as well as Pandas series and data frames.

Slicing enables writing clean, concise, and readable code.

examples:

```
>>> str_ = 'Python is awesome!'
>>> str_
'Python is awesome!'
>>> str_[:2]
'Py'
>>> str_[2:]
'thon is awesome!'
str_[:]
'Python is awesome!'
```